# How can I put xAxis in highcharts starting in the horizontal line when all values are in 0?

Tags: charts, highcharts

If I have a data like this:

```
     data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

this serie starts on the middle but I want what starts really close than the bottom line and not in the middle.Please take a look in this jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickwidth/ but change data by my example data (data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]), I test with min but in this scenario with all values in 0 did not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve with min: 0,minRange: 1 in xAxis

Answer (score 1):

I would do this simply by setting the yAxis min and max.

`Example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bKr74/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help, this give me an issue if I have a value different than 0, but finally I can solve, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can move xAxis down using `offset` property (***offset***: Number; The distance in pixels from the plot area to the axis line.):

```
    xAxis: {
        tickWidth: 10,
        offset: -155
    },
```

See [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkTQx/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this give me an issue if I have a value different than 0, but finally I can solve, thanks